# Sci-fi Energy Shields Effect (Halo)

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, effects

I have been messing around in Blender today trying to replicate this sort of effect: [image: Shields]

So far I have managed to create the correct sort of material and emulated the bulging of the shields: [image: Blender Attempt]

Node setup:
[image: Material Setup]

To do this I applied a solidify modifier, with a thickness of -0.01 (all other settings remained untouched), to a duplicate of the armour and then scaled the duplicated version up by 0.022. This for the most part looks alright, however; if you take a closer look you'll notice strange fragments were the meshes are intersecting.

Is there any way that I can avoid getting the mesh fragments appearing? Or do I need to do something completely different to get the desired outcome?

Cheers.

Comment: Solidify is definitely the quickest way, but as with all fast methods it has flaws. It will work well with relatively simple geometry, but will inevitably produce artifacts in more complex shapes. Either apply the modifier and fix it by hand, or do it all manually from scratch.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos fair enough. I was hoping that I would be able to get away with it just being a simple solution for the project I am working on. But if it requires me putting work into it, I will certainly try. Speaking of which, do you think applying the solidify modifier and then using a boolean modifier to remove the intersecting meshes could potentially work?

Comment: Don't bother with Booleans, they will produce more trouble than they solve. For a quick and dirty solution you may want to look into some sort of smoothing maybe, but again probably not as good as some manual work